# Json parsing help finding key and value

Tags: json

I am having trouble trying parse some json data. The problem is it is sometimes in a different format. I've  worked out the best way is to iterate through the data taking a jsonobject.

The problem I have is I need to check whether a specific key exists with a certain value. However the key maybe in the json multiple times and jsonobject.has doesn't  always return the key I am looking  for.

How would I check that a key "@type" exists with a value of "Recipe"?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I am trying to do this for an Android app, so I am using Java.